# Troubles connecting to a SQL Server Express instance on AWS

Tags: sql-server, aws, proxy

I'm trying to remote connect a SQL Server Express instance that is running on AWS on a `db.t2.micro`. I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11004)

I'm behind a proxy, but I should have route the address so the proxy is bypass for the IP of the SQL Server Express instance. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. I added a security group on the VPC Security groups on the EC2 console:
[image]
With this rule ( actually too broad, but just to confirm where the issue is )
[image]

by modifying the db instance ad add this security group, it accept incoming connections from remote.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express does not enable a TCP/IP listener by default. You must enable it using [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012) to allow remote connections.

Comment: Yeah I know, but this instance is on AWS so I cant have so much control over it